# Duplicate text when using Itext7 to read file

Tags: java, itext7

**Source :**

[image]

**Result :**

[image]

We use Itext7 to read PDF file but find that has some duplicate words,why?is about bold?

Comment: Can you include the images, code etc. inline?

Comment: Please share the pdfs in question for analysis. At first glance, though, it looks like the text extracted twice indeed is twice in the pdf at nearly the same position with merely a tiny offset to achieve a poor man's bold effect.

Comment: hello, thank you for your help.The file url is below.The coordinates I read are exactly the same.

https://github.com/winfredwl/resume-analysis/blob/master/src/main/resources/resumefiles/pdf/%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81%E7%BB%8F%E7%90%86-%E5%88%98%E7%8F%8A-%E6%8B%89%E5%8B%BE%E6%8B%9B%E8%81%98.pdf